# Keeps printing "hello world"

Tags: c++, vector

I am a newbie, so sorry if I make some silly mistakes.I am trying to create a program where I can get input from user and assign it to a vector, then print the vector. I dont know whats wrong with the program, it keeps printing out "Hello world". When I try to input something, the window just closes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> Assign_Vector(vector<int> data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
   {
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    data[i] = x;       
   }

return data;
}


int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
   vector<int> guesses;
   for (int i = 0; i < Assign_Vector(guesses).size(); i++)
  {
    cout << guesses[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: `Assign_Vector(guesses)` -- Explain what this is supposed to do.  A beginner would definitely not write something like this in this form.   How do you add items to a vector?  The very first thing you should have learned when using vector is `push_back`, but your code doesn't do anything like that.

Comment: Please debug the code, if you want to insert into vector you can use vector function like push_back

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger. In any case, being able to use a debugger is a necessary skill for any developer.

Comment: All your loops iterate over the vector, but where do you actually set the vectors size? Nowhere. Hence it's always empty and nothing happens. Secondly: `Assign_Vector(guesses).size()` will be evaluated in _every_ iteration of the loop, you must store the vector outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

`Assign_Vector` should take `data` by reference or you need to use the returned value.

As `guesses` is empty both of your for loops will never execute.

`Assign_Vector` is called for every iteration in your `for` loop in `main`, presumably this isn't what you wanted so should be moved before the for loop.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int>& Assign_Vector(vector<int>& data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
   {
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    data[i] = x;       
   }

return data;
}


int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
   const size_t numberOfGuesses = 10;
   vector<int> guesses(numberOfGuesses);
   Assign_Vector(guesses);
   for (int i = 0; i < guesses.size(); i++)
  {
    cout << guesses[i];
  }
}
```

Using c++ 11 for each loops can simplify your code a bit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int>& Assign_Vector(std::vector<int>& data)
{
    for (auto& i : data)
    {
        std::cin >> i;
    }
    return data;
}


int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
   const size_t numberOfGuesses = 10;
   std::vector<int> guesses(numberOfGuesses);
   for (auto& i : Assign_Vector(guesses))
   {
       std::cout << i;
   }
}
```